# How can I check if a string matches a route in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

I have a form allowing users to register for an account on my Laravel-powered web app. I have certain routes such as `/home` and `/logout`.

How can I check whether the username they attempt to register with matches any of these routes, without hardcoding it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am not entirely sure about your app but here's how I would do it.

```
private function getRouteSlugs()
{
    $slugs  = [];
    $routes = Route::getRoutes();

    foreach ($routes as $route)
    {
        $parts = explode('/', $route->getPath());
        foreach ($parts as $part)
        {
            $slug    = trim($part, '{}?');
            $slugs[] = $slug;
        }
    }

    return array_unique($slugs);
}
```

This function would help to get all the slugs that are registered within Laravel and then with a simple `in_array` you can check if that slug has been reserved.